# Webpack CommonJS Named Exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, commonjs

I have a simple library like so:

```
export const foo = () => {
  console.log("Hello")
}
```

I am trying to use Webpack to bundle it to CommonJS like so:

```
module.exports.foo = () => {
  console.log("Hello")
}
```

My webpack config is simple:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src-test"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name]-bundle.cjs.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  }
}
```

However, it's getting bundled under the default namespace like so:

```
module.exports = function (e) {
// ...
```

Why is this happening and how can I use named exports?

Comment: does `src-test` have exports?

Comment: Yes, `src-test` does have exports.

Comment: can you add them to your question?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am also having this issue.